# Opengl 3.2: Trying to render a triangle with shaders but output is distorted

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, rendering, jogl

I'm trying to port a tutorial from http://open.gl/drawing to Java using JOGL

I'm able to get output, but I'm receiving an unexpected output.

What is expected:

[image: Normal output, equilateral triangle]

And my output:

[image: my output, skewed isosceles triangle]

It seems that the triangle is not fully facing the camera, but the tutorial does not cover translation or rotation.

GLSL program compilation and linking:

```
float[] verts =       //Our triangle as a set of 2d coordinates
        {
             0.0f,  0.5f, //vertex 1, top at 0x, -0.5y
             0.5f, -0.5f  //vertex 2, right at 0.5x, -0.5y
            -0.5f, -0.5f  //vertex 3, left at -0.5x, -0.5y
        };

    IntBuffer vao = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
    gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao.get(0));

    IntBuffer vbo = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
    FloatBuffer vertBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(verts);

    gl.glGenBuffers(1, vbo);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.get(0));       
    gl.glBufferData(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer.limit() * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, vertBuffer, GL3.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    int vertexShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL3.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, vertProgram, null);
    gl.glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int fragmentShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL3.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, fragProgram, null);
    gl.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    program = gl.glCreateProgram();
    gl.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "outColor");
    gl.glLinkProgram(program);

    gl.glUseProgram(program);

    int positionAttribute = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
```

The display method:

```
    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glClear(GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Please don't hesitate to update the official JogAmp wiki when your ported tutorials are ready. We would be glad to look at your source code and some other beginners could benefit of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an error here:

```
float[] verts =       //Our triangle as a set of 2d coordinates
    {
         0.0f,  0.5f, //vertex 1, top at 0x, -0.5y
         0.5f, -0.5f  //vertex 2, right at 0.5x, -0.5y
        -0.5f, -0.5f  //vertex 3, left at -0.5x, -0.5y
    };
```

You are missing a comma after the first `-0.5f` (for vertex 2).